# How to stop youtube video or set buffer limit in youtube-api in android

Tags: android, video, buffer, android-youtube-api

I am using YouTube API to play my video, there are `play()` and `pause()` functions in the YouTube player. I need to stop the video at particular time. I am using `pause()` but the background of the video gets buffering. How do I stop buffering the video after a particular time limit? In webview there is a option start and end tag in URL to buffer like below,

> https://www.youtube.com/v/K_AdxJWFUh4&start=0&end=30

**Note: I am using Youtube Player to play video not WEBVIEW**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check This Code

```
public class YouTube extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {

    public static final String API_KEY = "<---YOUR KEY--->";
    public static final String VIDEO_ID = "<--VIDEO ID YOU WANT TO PLAY--->";
    private static YouTubePlayer player;

    TextView text;

    //this is the end time in milliseconds (65th second)
    public int endTime = 5600;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
        text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
        YouTubePlayerView youTubePlayerView = (YouTubePlayerView)findViewById(R.id.youtubeplayerview);
        youTubePlayerView.initialize(API_KEY, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationFailure(Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult result) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
        "onInitializationFailure()",
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {

        MyActivity.player = player; //necessary to access inside Runnable

        //start the video at 36th second
        player.loadVideo(VIDEO_ID, 0);

        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(() -> {
            //For every 1 second, check the current time and endTime
            if(MyActivity.player.getCurrentTimeMillis() <= endTime) {
                text.setText("Video Playing at " + MyActivity.player.getCurrentTimeMillis());
                handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
            } else {
                handler.removeCallbacks(this); //no longer required
                text.setText(" Reached " + endTime);
                MyActivity.player.pause(); //and Pause the video
            }
        }, 1000);
    }
}
```

Layout XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="http://android-er.blogspot.com/"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:autoLink="web" />

    <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
        android:id="@+id/youtubeplayerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```